# Get value from db in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have following code. It is giving me list of events. In that I want get patient name.

I have patient Id, but I am confused how can I get patient name using that id.

```
events = db.PTSessions.Where(x => x.OfficeIdFk == user.OfficeIdFk || x.PTIdFk == user.PTId).Where((a => a.AppointmentDate > start &&
                (a.AppointmentTimeTo < end))).Select(m => new EventViewModel
                {
                    id = m.SessionId,
                    title = m.AppointmentReason,
                    start = m.AppointmentTimeFrom,
                    end = m.AppointmentTimeTo,
                    allDay = false,
                    patientid = m.PatientIdFk,
                    appointmentstatus = m.AppointmentStatus,
                    patientname = db.Patients.Where(p => p.PatientId == m.PatientIdFk).Select(p => p.PatientName).ToString()
                }).ToList();
```

in above code I can't get patientname and getting error also.

Thanks

Comment: Include the error description to the post, please.

Comment: @Jackdaw I am getting this error : The specified type member 'PatientName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @Nic Do you have proper Relation between PTSessions and Patients entity? if yes then inside PTSession entity you will find Patient entity (x.Patient like this), that will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
patientname = db.Patients.Where(p => p.PatientId == m.PatientIdFk)
.Select(p => p.PatientName).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I tried this and getting this error : The specified type member 'PatientName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @Nic Pls post Patient class too